# Unable to generate Models using InspectDB

Tags: python, node.js, django, mongodb, database-migration

I am using Django `inspectdb` to auto generate models from an existing mongodb database deployed on the cloud. It was configured using NodeJS and now client wants to change it to Django.

In my `settings.py`, I have:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'dbname',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'mongodb+srv://string'
            }  
        }
}
```

When I run `python manage.py inspectdb`, I get the following error for each table:

```
# The error was: 'NoneType' object is not table_name
# Unable to inspect table 'table_name'
```

I have the following packages installed in my virtualenv:

```
Package           Version
----------------- ------------
asgiref           3.7.2
Django            4.1.12
djongo            1.3.6
dnspython         2.4.2
pip               23.2.1
pymongo           3.12.3
pytz              2023.3.post1
setuptools        68.2.2
sqlparse          0.2.4
typing_extensions 4.8.0
wheel             0.41.2
```

Comment: Try    'python manage.py inspectdb --table=table_name' command.

Comment: error @NayemJamanTusher manage.py inspectdb: error: unrecognized arguments: --table=users